# Is returning a reference from static method thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class:

```
class PrintStringDataBuilder
{
    PrintStringDataBuilder() { }
    public static GetInstance()
    {
        return new PrintStringDataBuilder();
    }

    //other class methods and fields, properties
}
```

Accessed from client Code as:

```
PrintStringDataBuilder instance = PrintStringDataBuilder.GetInstance();
```

**Is above call thread-safe?**

Edit: Just trying to avoid writing 
PrintStringDataBuilder builder = new PrintStringDataBuilder(); multiple times in asp.net mvc web app. There are no other static methods, static fields or static properties in the PrintStringDataBuilder class.

Comment: That really depends on what `new PrintStringDataBuilder()` does.  Are you trying to make it a Singleton?  If so, this is not doing that.  If not, why do you have a static `GetInstance()` method when you could just call the constructor.

Comment: Do you have a  private constructor `PrintStringDataBuilder` How are you other fields initialized?

Comment: Why the down-vote? I think it's a good question

Comment: I'd rename your method to `Create`. `GetInstance` sounds too much like a singleton.

Answer (score 11):

Yes? Without knowing the internals of the constructor of that class, you could say that calling `GetInstance()` was thread safe. Any methods on that instance would not be guaranteed to be thread safe though, particularly since you didnt present any of those methods.

This is simply known as the factory pattern.

EDIT: If you are trying to return a singleton, you can do it like so:

.NET 4+

```
private static Lazy<PrintStringDataBuilder> _instance = new Lazy<PrintStringDataBuilder>(() =>
  {
      return new PrintStringDataBuilder();
  });

public static PrintStringDataBuilder GetInstance()
{
    return _instance.Value;
}
```

.NET 3.5 and below

```
private static PrintStringDataBuilder _instance = null;
private static object _lockObject = new object();

public static PrintStringDataBuilder GetInstance()
{
    if(_instance == null)
    {
         lock(_lockObject)
         {
              if(_instance == null)
                 _instance = new PrintStringDataBuilder();
         }
    }

    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the constructor is thread safe (it doesnt do anything). Are you trying to return a singleton?

Comment: No, just trying to avoid writing PrintStringDataBuilder builder = new PrintStringDataBuilder(); multiple times

Comment: You're not saving a lot of keystrokes by making a factory method there, and in fact calling the static method is even more text =D

Answer (score 5):

By 'threadsafe' are you concerned that multiple threads calling your static method are going to get the SAME PrintStringDataBuilder? The answer to that is NO, and the call is thread-safe.

Having said that, no one can tell from the small snippet you give whether the rest of the class is, or its constructor. There are many reasons why the class instances aren't thread-safe. if they refer to static properties without locking is an example.

Answer (score 3):

Entering a method is always thread safe. Accessing shared data might not be. So this code is thread safe because there is not shared data.

If your intention here is to have a single instance of `PrintStringDataBuilder` for all threads then for that purpose your code will not work. You need proper singleton. In .NET 4 the code can be very compact:

```
private static Lazy<PrintStringDataBuilder> instance = new Lazy<PrintStringDataBuilder>();

public static PrintStringDataBuilder Instance
{
    get { return instance.Value; }
}
```

This will guarantee that in every thread `PrintStringDataBuilder.Instance` will point to the same and only one instance of your `PrintStringDataBuilder` object which will be created in a lazy manner i.e. only when it is first used and no sooner.

Answer (score 1):

@Tejs,

Actually, in .NET you do not need to use the double-check lock mechanism - there are better ways around it.  But if you choose to do so, your implementation of the double-check lock is incorrect and not truly thread-safe.  The compiler could optimize away the initialization of the `_instance = new PrintStringDataBuilder();` - there are 3 possible modifications to make your example truly thread-safe:

1. initialize the static member inline - definitely the easiest!

```
    private static PrintStringDataBuilder _instance = new PrintStringDataBuilder;
    public static PrintStringDataBuilder GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }
```

2 . use the 'volatile' keyword to ensure that the initialization of the `PrintStringDataBuilder` is not optimized by the JIT.

```
private static volatile PrintStringDataBuilder _instance = null;
private static object _lockObject = new object();

public static PrintStringDataBuilder GetInstance()
{
    if(_instance == null)
    {
         lock(_lockObject)
         {
              if(_instance == null)
              {
                 _instance = new PrintStringDataBuilder();
              }
         }
    }

    return _instance;
}
```

3 . Use Interlocked.Exchange with double-check lock:

```
private static PrintStringDataBuilder _instance = null;
private static object _lockObject = new object();

public static PrintStringDataBuilder GetInstance()
{
    if(_instance == null)
    {
         lock(_lockObject)
         {
              if(_instance == null)
              {
                 var temp = new PrintStringDataBuilder();
                 Interlocked.Exchange(ref _instance, temp);
              }
         }
    }

    return _instance;
}
```

Hope this helps.